# When using Doctrine 2 custom annotations, what's the best way to get an array of all entity classes that have a specific annotation?

Tags: annotations, doctrine-orm

I'm reading this [documentation article about Custom Annotations in Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html). I understand that I can use `$reader->getClassAnnotations($reflClass)` to retrieve the annotations on a particular class. What's the best way to get a list of all entity classes that have a specific annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\PHPDriver($entities_path );

$classes = $driver->getAllClassNames();

foreach ($classes as $key => $class) {     

      $reader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();

      $annotationReader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader(
                                              $reader, 
                                              new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache()
                                           );

      $reflClass = new ReflectionClass("\Entities\\".$reportableClass);
      $annotation = $annotationReader->getClassAnnotation(
                                                     $reflClass, 
                                                     'Custom_Annotation'
                                                  );
      if (is_null($annotation)) {
          unset($classes[$key]);
      }
}
```

The AbstractFileDriver(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AbstractFileDriver.php) documentation of Doctrine said:

> Base driver for file-based metadata drivers.
>   
>   A file driver operates in a mode where it loads the mapping files of
>   individual classes on demand. This requires the user to adhere to the
>   convention of 1 mapping file per class and the file names of the
>   mapping files must correspond to the full class name, including
>   namespace, with the namespace delimiters '\', replaced by dots '.'.

Also you could use instead of the PhpDriver, the DatabaseDriver (Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver.php).